# Why cross-thread exception only thrown when you change visible properties of a control?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have noticed that if I change a visible property of a control, such as label1.Text, from another thread that did not create the control, Visual Studio will throw an invalid cross-thread operation exception.  But if I change a non-visible property of the control, say label1.Name, then no exception is thrown.  Why is that?

Comment: Th only rule you need to concern yourself with is "*only update the UI from the UI thread*"... full stop... There are times where this will not throw an exception (for one of several reasons), however you are playing a game of *Russian Roulette*. So best use the *async and await pattern*, or otherwise marshal back to the UI thread when you need to update it

Comment: You can create a Dialog in a Thread (whatever may this mean here) other than the main UI Thread (the Thread started when you first show your UI), it's not *forbidden*. What you cannot do is to try and change UI elements from a different Thread. Why would you do that in the first place? You can run a Task, pass to the method it starts an [IProgress<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) delegate that is created in the main UI Thread (a `Progress<T>` object that creates a callback) and use its `Report()` method to send data to the UI Thread, which then handles it.

Comment: If you have (or it's possible to generate) some form of concurrency, IMO, it's better to put a Lock() in the callback and have a procedure that doesn't linger in-place for no good reason (i.e., whatever you do there, design it to make it quick and/or enqueue the work to a proxy that handles the results)

Comment: Good comments.  The pattern I mentioned in my question is very consistent, not random at all.  I feel it's a bug in Visual Studio (or C#?).  Regardless of whether a property is visible or not, if you could potentially change it on two threads, it can lead to all kinds of problems.  If anyone knows the reason for this pattern, I'd like to know.  I feel the emphasis on only update the UI from the UI thread is probably a way to make multi-threading easier to follow for beginner .NET programmers.  The logic underneath is the pitfalls of concurrency, regardless of if UI is involved.

Comment: @GirlSpider - The rule, for all programmers, regardless of experience, is "do not create, access, or update UI elements from a non-UI thread." UI elements are not thread-safe and they rely on the message pump/dispatcher on the UI thread to work.